# How to use UISwipeGestureRecognizer on UIButton?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a UIbutton which i want to work as a joystick. So i am trying to add some gesture recognizer on the same button. 
I have this in my code right now:

```
@implementation CUETutorialSixteenClusterRootController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"CUETutorialLandscapeClusterRootController" bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _leftInActiveView = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _rightInActiveViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _centerInActiveViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        _centerActiveViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        UIImageView * inActLeftView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 82, 98)] autorelease];
        inActLeftView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1-am-station_01.png"];
        [_leftInActiveView addObject:inActLeftView];


        UIImageView * inActRightView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 82, 98)] autorelease];
        inActRightView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1-am-station_03.png"];
        [_rightInActiveViews addObject:inActRightView];

        NSArray * imagesName = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1_start.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"2_apptray_audio_selected.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"2_apptray_phone_selected.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"4_phonemenu_contacts_highlighted.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"5_phonemenu_recentcalls_highlighted.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"6_recent_calls.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"7_bottom_hit.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"8_recent_call_details.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"9_calling.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"9_calling_myphone.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"9_call_ended.png"],nil];
        NSLog(@"Count:%d",[imagesName count]);
        for (int i =0; i<11; i++) {
            UIImageView * inActCenterView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 226, 98)] autorelease];
            inActCenterView.image = [imagesName objectAtIndex:i];
            [_centerActiveViews addObject:inActCenterView];
            [_centerInActiveViews addObject:inActCenterView];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)showClusterType:(clusterType)cluster{
    switch (cluster) {
            //Base Cluster is analog
        case kClusterTypeBase:
        {
            [self.fullClusterContainerView removeFromSuperview];
            [self.view addSubview:self.baseClusterContainerView];
            [self.view addSubview:self.baseClusterImageView];

            CUETutorialSixteenAplicationHomeScreen * clusAppScreen = [[CUETutorialSixteenAplicationHomeScreen alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
            clusAppScreen.dataSource = self;
            clusAppScreen.rootController = self;

            self.clusterHomeScreen = clusAppScreen;

            [self.baseClusterContainerView addSubview:clusAppScreen.view];
            [clusAppScreen release];

            /*
             [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.steeringWheelImageView];
             [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.promptLabel];
             [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[self.view viewWithTag:kFavDownButton]];
             [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[self.view viewWithTag:kFavUpButton]];
             [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[self.view viewWithTag:kRightButtonUp]];
             [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[self.view viewWithTag:kRightButtonLeft]];
             [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[self.view viewWithTag:kRightButtonRight]];
             [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[self.view viewWithTag:kRightButtonDown]];
             [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[self.view viewWithTag:kRightButtonCenter]];
             */

            [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.promptLabel];
        }
            break;
            //Full cluster is digital 
        case kClusterTypeFull:
        {
            [self.baseClusterImageView removeFromSuperview];
            [self.baseClusterContainerView removeFromSuperview];
            [self.view addSubview:self.fullClusterContainerView];

        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

/*
 // Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
 - (void)loadView
 {
 }
 */


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _step =1;
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer;

    recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
    [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)];
    [self.gestureRecieverButton addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [recognizer release];
    recognizer = nil;

    recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
    [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown)];
    [self.gestureRecieverButton addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [recognizer release];
    recognizer = nil;

    recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
    [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
    [self.gestureRecieverButton addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [recognizer release];
    recognizer = nil;

    recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
    [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
    [self.gestureRecieverButton addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [recognizer release];
    recognizer = nil;


}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    time=0;

    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}
-(void)dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
    [_leftInActiveView release];
    [_rightInActiveViews release];
    [_centerActiveViews release];
    [_centerInActiveViews release];
}

-(void)animateToView:(UIView *)aview{
    if(aview){
        //CGRect rect = [aview convertRect:aview.bounds toView:self.view];
        CGRect rect = aview.frame;
        [self animateHandFromRect:self.promptLabel.frame toRect:rect];
    }
    else{
        [self animateHandToNSValueRect:nil];
    }
}

-(void)finishTutorial{
    [self displayPromptText:@"TUTORIAL COMPLETE"];
    [self displayNavigationBarWithTitle:@"TUTORIAL COMPLETE"];

    [self performBlock:^{
        [self.clusterHomeScreen.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self showScoresScreen];
    }afterDelay:1];
}
-(void)animateHandToCenterButton
{
    [self displayPromptText:@"TAP RIGHT SIDE CENTER BUTTON"];
    [self displayNavigationBarWithTitle:@"TAP RIGHT SIDE CENTER BUTTON"];
    [self animateToView:self.rCenterButton];
}
-(void)animateHandToDownButton {
    [self displayPromptText:@"TAP RIGHT SIDE DOWN BUTTON"];
    [self displayNavigationBarWithTitle:@"TAP RIGHT SIDE DOWN BUTTON"];
    [self animateToView:self.rDownButton];

}

-(void)animateHandToUpButton{
    [self displayPromptText:@"TAP RIGHT SIDE UP BUTTON"];
    [self displayNavigationBarWithTitle:@"TAP RIGHT SIDE UP BUTTON"];
    [self animateToView:self.rUpButton];

}

-(void)replaceCallScreen{
    [self performBlock:^{
        [self pressedRightButtonCenter];
    } afterDelay:2.0];

}

-(void)changeTimer {
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(startTicking) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)startTicking {
    time = time +1;
    self.clusterHomeScreen.callTimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"00:0%d",time];
    if (time==9) {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
-(void) animateHandToVolUpButton {
    [self displayPromptText:@"TAP VOLUME UP BUTTON"];
    [self displayNavigationBarWithTitle:@"TAP VOLUME UP BUTTON"];
    [self animateToView:self.rVolUpButton];

}

-(void) animateHandToVolDownButton {
    [self displayPromptText:@"TAP VOLUME DOWN BUTTON"];
    [self displayNavigationBarWithTitle:@"TAP VOLUME DOWN BUTTON"];
    [self animateToView:self.rVolDownButton];
}

-(void)removeVolumeView {
    [self pressedRightButtonCenter];
    [self.clusterHomeScreen runNextStep];
}

-(void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"Swipe received.%@",recognizer);
}

-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{    
    if ([sender tag]==kRightButtonDown && _step ==1)
    {
        [self pressedRightButtonDown];
        [self displayPromptText:@"TAP AGAIN"];
        [self displayNavigationBarWithTitle:@"TAP AGAIN"];
        _step++;
    }
    else if ([sender tag]==kRightButtonDown && _step == 2)
    {
        [self pressedRightButtonDown];
        [self animateToView:self.rCenterButton];
        [self displayPromptText:@"TAP CENTER BUTTON"];
        [self displayNavigationBarWithTitle:@"TAP CENTER BUTTON"];
        _step++;
    }
    else if ([sender tag]==kRightButtonCenter && _step == 3)
    {
        [self pressedRightButtonCenter];
        [self animateToView:self.rUpButton];
        _step++;
    }
    else if ([sender tag]==kRightButtonUp && _step == 4)
    {
        [self pressedRightButtonUp];
        [self displayPromptText:@"TAP CENTER BUTTON"];
        [self displayNavigationBarWithTitle:@"TAP CENTER BUTTON"];
        [self animateToView:self.rCenterButton];

        _step++;
    }

    else if ([sender tag]==kRightButtonCenter && _step==5){
        [self pressedRightButtonCenter];
        [self displayPromptText:@"TAP DOWN BUTTON"];
        [self displayNavigationBarWithTitle:@"TAP DOWN BUTTON"];
        [self animateToView:self.rDownButton];
        _step++;
    }
    else if([sender tag]==kRightButtonDown && _step==6){
        [self pressedRightButtonDown];
        [self animateToView:self.rCenterButton];
        [self displayPromptText:@"TAP CENTER BUTTON"];
        [self displayNavigationBarWithTitle:@"TAP CENTER BUTTON"];
        _step++;
    }
    else if ([sender tag]==kRightButtonCenter && _step==7){
        [self pressedRightButtonCenter];
        _step++;
    }
    else if ([sender tag]==kRightButtonCenter && _step==8)
    {
        [self pressedRightButtonCenter];
        self.clusterHomeScreen.callTimer.hidden = NO;
        [self.clusterHomeScreen runNextStep];
        _step++;
    }
    else if ([sender tag]==kRightButtonCenter && _step==9)
    {
        self.clusterHomeScreen.callTimer.hidden = YES;
        [self pressedRightButtonCenter];

        _step++;
    }
    else if ([sender tag]==kRightButtonCenter && _step==10)
    {
        [self pressedRightButtonCenter];
        [self finishTutorial];
    }
    else {
        [self displayVisualFeedback:kVisualFeedBackIncorrectAnswer];
    }
}


#pragma CUEClusterHomeSreenDataSource Methods
-(NSInteger)numberOfViewsForLeftScreen {

    return [_leftActiveViews count];
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfViewsForRightScreen{
    return [_rightActiveViews count];
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfViewsForCenterScreen {
    return [_centerActiveViews count];
}



-(UIImageView *)inActiveViewForLeftScreenAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{
    //if((index < [_leftInActiveView count]) && (index >=0)){
    return [_leftInActiveView objectAtIndex:index];
    //}
    //return nil;
}
-(UIImageView *)activeViewForLeftScreenAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{
    //  if((index < [_leftActiveViews count]) && (index >=0)){
    return [_leftActiveViews objectAtIndex:index];
    //}
    //return nil;
}
-(UIImageView *)inActiveViewForRightScreenAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{
    //if((index < [_rightInActiveViews count]) && (index >=0)){
    return [_rightInActiveViews objectAtIndex:index];
    //}
    //return nil;
}
-(UIImageView *)activeViewForRightScreenAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{
    //if((index < [_rightActiveViews count]) && (index >=0)){
    return [_rightActiveViews objectAtIndex:index];
    //}
    //return nil;
}

-(UIImageView *)inActiveViewForCenterScreenAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{
    //if((index < [_leftInActiveView count]) && (index >=0)){
    return [_centerInActiveViews objectAtIndex:index];
    //}
    //return nil;
}
-(UIImageView *)activeViewForCenterScreenAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{
    //  if((index < [_leftActiveViews count]) && (index >=0)){
    return [_centerActiveViews objectAtIndex:index];
    //}
    //return nil;
}
```

This is the error i am getting now:
-`[CUETutorialSixteenClusterRootController handleSwipeFrom:]:` unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79b71b0
2012-03-28 13:25:55.724 CUETrainer[1788:11f03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception '`NSInvalidArgumentException`', reason: '-`[CUETutorialSixteenClusterRootController handleSwipeFrom:]:` unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79b71b0'

But its not actually doing anything.
Please help!!!!

Comment: See the edit. But still not working.

Comment: is handleSwipeFrom declared in .h ?

Comment: Yes it is. And now what's happening is this is working for swipe from top to bottom but crashing for everything else.

Comment: What is self.gestureRecieverButton?

Comment: A UIButton declared in parent class.

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava: Tried nil but still doesn't work for other swipes

Comment: can you show me your entire .m file.. ?

Comment: I can but don't know if it would make any sense. It has a lot more things.

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava:see the edit i replaced the code with whole .m code

Comment: try with different instances of recognizers instead of just one... four different in your case.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9423/discussion-between-ashutosh-and-ankit-srivastava)

Comment: @Ashutosh posted my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says `unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79b71b0'` most probably the names in .h and .m are different..

Answer (score 1):

The target of the gesture recognizer needs to be the object that implements the selector. What's happening now when a swipe happens is that the gesture recognizer is doing `[self.gestureReceiverButton handleSwipeFrom:recognizer]`

You probably want this:

```
recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
```

Comment: i changed self.gestureRecognizer to self but its still not working

Answer (score 0):

Change every instance of:

`recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];`

to

`recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];`

Problem solved. Be very careful with your `@selectors`, what you place in this macro is NOT validated by the compiler. Code complete will help you with this.

Also you are adding four gesture recognizers to one view, while you can accomplish the same task with one. You can combine the valid directions using the bitwise OR operator, like so:

`[recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown)];`